# Offline use of google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to use google maps API in my android application.(*the application does not require internet connection*)
Is it possible to download a map file of a certain city, then make it available for offline use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with Google Maps tiles, but you may try to integrate Android API v2 with OpenStreetMap or other tiles.

Comment: You can not do that because of license restrictions. See https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12, bullet 10.1.1.g.

Comment: @vitakot Read the definition of "Content": 8.1.b ;)

Comment: I do not see any discrepancy. The license clearly state that you can not use Google Maps API in conjuction with non-Google maps. It is mentioned in all maps related APIs as well. For instance, you can not use Geocoder, Directions..., nothing. Simply, the 10.1.1.g says "No Use of Content (all stuff you can obtain via Google Maps Api) without a Google Map" and that's exactly what you advise in your answer...

Comment: @vitakot The question doesn't clearly say what `google maps API in my android application` they want to use. My assumption is Google Maps API there means Google Maps Android API v2 (plain map with some `Marker`s) and your seem to be Google Directions API and similar APIs.